# Why is my .js file going to a 404?

Tags: url, include, absolute-path, uploading

I'm using Wordpress, and I linked some masonry jQuery library files and when trying to visit the .js file, it goes to a 404. However, my custom functions are viewable and so is the jQuery .js file. Why might it be going to a 404? I spent 1 hour trying to figure out why my function wasn't working and it turns out the file wasn't being loaded properly.

This is how I am linking to the jQuery files:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/jquery.eachdelay-0.0.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason, `custom.js` works fine, but not the others. I have it uploaded properly. It says "Page not found" when I try to visit the other files in the browser.

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Please give your blog URL and let us check it. Most probably you're not good at debugging html stuff.

Comment: I cannot give the URL. Sorry.

Comment: I know this may seem silly, but just to be sure: You have uploaded `jquery.masonry.min.js` and `jquery.eachdelay-0.0.1.js` to the `js` folder, right?

Comment: try opening those URLs manually with a command line tool (like wget or curl) if you still get 404, then check your .htaccess file, there may be related rules on this file to force 404. note that on linux servers, filenames and folder names are case-sensitive.

Comment: If you visit the URL in a browser and the file is not there, then you did not upload it properly.  Perhaps it timed out, maybe you accidently put it in another directory, etc.  You did not mention anything about your upload methods.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes, I am actually going to the url domain.com/js/ and then clicking the file and it goes to a "Page not Found" shown in my Wordpress blog.

Comment: @Doug: Sure, that means the file isn't there and it isn't how you're embedding it that's the problem, but did you upload it? Files don't appear on the server like magic. You have to upload them to your server.

Comment: @icktoofay I don't mean to be an ass, but yes, I did upload it. I know how to upload things to FTP. I mean, it wouldn't show up in the directory under domain.com/js if I didn't upload it correctly. That was the reason why I pointed it out that I clicked on the file and it went to a 404 while the others ones didn't.

Comment: @Doug:  **404 means it is not there**...  either the URL is wrong or you're looking at the wrong directory on your server.

Comment: @Doug: Thanks for the answer. I didn't mean to suggest you didn't; I was just wondering, since some people don't. If we can filter those who do and those who don't, we can help people better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the conclusion:

I created another file and deleted the old one then renamed the new one with the same name and it didn't work. So, I just ended up creating a file and naming it something other than the original default and then pasted the JS contents in to the new file I made and viola!

I think its a caching problem, I don't know how to fix it and why it happened but this was my solution. Also, people should not be so hasty to assume that the 404 means that I do not know how to upload a file and that I uploaded it to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

try using an absolute URL path for the js file.